# Trying to split a column of object datatype to create a separate column in a DataFrame. Getting the error: "'float object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df['zip_code'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x:x[-5:])
```

In a Dataframe `'df'`, I've a column `'address'`. Few values of `'address'` columns are:

```
0       0174 Michelle Gateway\nMendozaberg, OK 22690
1    1076 Carney Fort Apt. 347\nLoganmouth, SD 05113
2    87025 Mark Dale Apt. 269\nNew Sabrina, WV 05113
3              823 Reid Ford\nDelacruzside, MA 00813
4               679 Luna Roads\nGreggshire, VA 11650
Name: address, dtype: object
```

My target is to create a new column 'zip_code' that is going to contain the last 5 digits from the above values.

Although, none of the columns are of float datatype, still, I'm getting the error "float object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas method slicing with `str`, which working with missing values correctly:

```
df['zip_code'] = df['address'].str[-5:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'text':[' 0174 Michelle Gateway\nMendozaberg, OK 22690','1076 Carney Fort Apt. 347\nLoganmouth, SD 05113']})
```

Extract last digits, five of them using regex

```
df['code']=df.text.str.extract('.*([0-9]{5})')

    text                                            code
0   0174 Michelle Gateway\nMendozaberg, OK 22690    22690
1   1076 Carney Fort Apt. 347\nLoganmouth, SD 05113 05113
```